# Why float_format puts extra zero when converting float to percentage with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have the following code piece that saves the given DataFrame into a CSV file.
While doing that, I would like that **33.3** will be saved as **33.3%** and **44.4** will be saved as **44.4%**.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [33.3, 44.4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_csv("temp.csv", float_format = '%.1f%%')
```

But when I run this code, the output becomes as the following in my temp.csv file:

[image]

I do not want the extra zeroin my percentage values. For instance, instead of 33.30%, I would like to see 33.3% in the CSV file.

And since I specify that `float_format = '%.1f%%'`, then I expect to see 33.3% (instead of 33.30%) but it is not happening.

How can this problem be solved so that I eliminate the extra zeros in my percentage values?

Comment: csv is not a format file type , try with excel not csv

Comment: In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: 

In [2]: d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [33.3, 44.4]}

In [3]: 

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

In [4]: 

In [4]: from io import StringIO

In [5]: out = StringIO()

In [6]: df.to_csv(out,  float_format = '%.1f%%')

In [7]: out.getvalue()
Out[7]: ',col1,col2\n0,1,33.3%\n1,2,44.4%\n'

In [8]: print(out.getvalue())
,col1,col2
0,1,33.3%
1,2,44.4%

Not seeing a  problem

Comment: @hd1, have you tried to save it to a csv file and check the content by opening the file? And if I open the CSV file in another program and read the content, I still see the extra zero.

Comment: @edn I posted what I ran above